# Fetch attachment from devops workitem through Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

Retrieving Devops WorkItem attachment using Azure LogicApps throwing redirect error while using RestApi call

I am trying to get the attachment from a Azure devops workitem and copy it to a folder through Logic Apps in Azure. I am trying to use the Http Request action and call the api in the below format,

https://dev.azure.com///_apis/wit/attachments/?api-version=5.0

But the action is erroring out with 'Redirect' in the error code instead of giving any output to process further. Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: How you are getting the attachment link here?